# how do i set the height of each row in my gridlayout in xml

Tags: android, xml

Hi guys I am new to android. I want to use a GridLayout that has 1 column and 4 rows to structure my application.

```
   <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:rowCount="4"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</GridLayout>
```

The only thing is I want my rows to have different heights. Is there a way to specify this for each row in xml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can !

You need to create a CustomGridAdapter which allows you to specify the size of each row :
You should take a look at this tutorial :
http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100

Once you have created your grid_item.xml, you can edit in java the size of each row in the OnCreate() on your application.

For example :
Set your grid_item.xml as below :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:src="@drawable/android_logo" >

</ImageView>
```

And then in your CustomGridAdapter you can set the width/height of each ImageView, the "wrap_content" of the linearLayout means that your row will do the size of your ImageView.

Cheers !